# putpixel with pyglet

Tags: python, image, pyglet

I'm new to pyglet. I'd like to change a pixel from black to white at each `on_draw` iteration. So after 1000 iterations, there should be exactly 1000 white pixels in the window. However, I'd like to avoid calling 1000 draw operations in `on_draw` for that. So I'd like to create an image, do an RGB putpixel on the image, and blit the image to the screen. How can I do that? The pyglet documentation, the examples and the source code aren't too helpful on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one gave a really good answer to this.
I'll place one here:

```
import pyglet
from random import randint

width, height = 500, 500
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=width, height=height)
image = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((255,255,255,255)).create_image(width, height)

data = image.get_image_data().get_data('RGB', width*3)
new_image = b''

for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
    pixel = bytes([randint(0,255)]) + bytes([randint(0,255)]) + bytes([randint(0,255)])
    new_image += pixel

image.set_data('RGB', width*3, new_image)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0, 0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Essentially, what this does is it creates a white image, that in itself can be drawn in the window. But seeing as we want to do `putpixel`, i've modified every pixel in the white image as a demo.

Can be used in junction with:

- https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.image.ImageData-class.html#get_region

Which can be used to optemize the image manipulation further.

Comment: Thank you for the code pointers! Could you please add code to `on_draw` which changes the color of 1 pixel of `image`? Should it be something like this? `pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((200,100,0,255)).creat‌e_image(1,1).blit_into(image, x, y, 0)`, or is there a more efficient way of doing `putpixel`?

Comment: @pts I'll respond in a few hours to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is too late to help you, but there are ways to do this. For example, blit_into, which modifies a loaded image:

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window(600, 600)
background = pyglet.resource.image('my600x600blackbackground.bmp')
pix = pyglet.resource.image('singlewhitepixel.bmp').get_image_data()

def update(dt):
    background.blit_into(pix, x, y, 0) #specify x and y however you want

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    background.blit(0,0)

pyglet.clock.schedule(update, 1.0/30) #30 frames per second
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient seeing as you need to load a entire .bmp pixel from disk. If your CPU is faster than your HDD, I'd suggest doing: `pix = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((255,255,255,255)).create_image(1,1)` where `1,1` could be replaced with however pig of a "pixel cluster" you want to create.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the question is aimed at specifically this toy example, or the more general case where you want to alter an image dynamically. Either way, it's not a per-frame operation. It is hard to conjure a use-case where you would be loading so many individual pixels that it would impact performance in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no easy way to do this in pyglet. So I've given up on using pyglet.